# How do you propagate dependencies through a large codebase using Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Almost all dependency injection examples/tutorials walk through a case of injecting dependencies at the top level of the program:

```
class Program
{
    Main(string args[])
    {
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddSeriLog())... // etc.

        var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

        var myClass = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<MyClass>(serviceProvider);
        myClass.Run();
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    ILogger<MyClass> _logger;
    public MyClass (ILogger<MyClass> logger) { _logger = logger; }
    public void Run() 
    {
        var nestedClass = new MyNestedClass(_logger); // <- Here! Surely this isn't right!
        nestedClass.DoSomeWork();
    }
}

class MyNestedClass
{
    ILogger<MyNestedClass> _logger;
    public MyNestedClass (ILogger<MyNestedClass> logger) { _logger = logger; }
    public void DoSomeWork() {};
}
```

This is all fine. What happens though, when MyClass instantiates further classes that also require an ILogger instance? Are these expected to be passed explicitly down the hierarchy from the _logger instance that exists in MyClass? This seems counter to how I expect DependencyInjection to work (i.e. it's a load of work). How would this be done in practice?

The only approach I can see that's consistent with how the existing dependency injection works, is to pass through a ServiceProvider into MyClass, and then within MyClass to call

```
var nestedClass = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<MyNestedClass>(serviceProvider);
```

But again, this is crazy - because I'm passing serviceProvider downstream to other classes etc.

Comment: "Almost all dependency injection examples/tutorials". Such as? "Surely this isn't right!" Correct; it isn't proper way of implementing DI.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAOCe-2nXqc&ab_channel=IAmTimCorey, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection etc. My point is that in the tutorials they cover the {Main Method -> Calls Single Class} situation

Comment: The common thread is that those are simplistic examples intended to teach the very basics of DI. You're using those to extrapolate how DI would work in more complex scenarios, which is understandable but wholly incorrect. Why not instead find more complex examples and compare the way they work to your understanding?

Comment: I'm likely biased, but I find many MS provided docs on DI (such as the one you pointed at) a poor intros to DI. That specific doc you are referring to is intended to get the reader up and running with the .NET DI infrastructure in a ASP.NET Core *Web application*, but is unsuited as intro to DI principles, practices, and patterns. Instread, you might find [this freely available first chapter](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-1) of [my book](https://mng.bz/BYNl) a more practical introduction to DI.

Comment: As I see it, in his video, Tim Corey calls `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` at startup more as an exercise to show of what happens when exceptions are thrown, because calling `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` at startup to create a component (i.e. `GreetingService` in his case) is a weird thing to do, because it circumvents the DI system (as `GrettingService` will not be created by the container but by `ActivatorUtilities`). A more common way is to call `host.Services.GetRequiredService<IGreetingService>()`, which actually allows to request the interface).

Answer (score 3):

In your example, `MyNestedClass` is a dependency of `MyClass` so it should be injected instead:

```cs
class MyClass
{
    MyNestedClass _nestedClass;

    public MyClass (MyNestedClass nestedClass)
    {
         _nestedClass = nestedClass;
    }

    public void Run() 
    {
        _nestedClass.DoSomeWork();
    }
}
```

Comment: So I would have to first register `MyNestedClass` within the ServiceCollection. If we consider a larger graph of classes where I want to pass a Logger through to each one. Am I not going to end up with a very large set of dependencies that need registering? Do all dependencies need explicitly creating in this manner, instead of with a static singleton Logger pattern?

Comment: You dont need explicit registration. `services.AddLogging(...` will register the Illoger for you.

Comment: I updated @Thomas' answer a bit to make his point more clear, which is that `MyClass` should only get injected with the dependencies it *itself* is using. As it only used `ILogger<T>` to instantiate `MyNestedClass`, but nested class should be injected instead, `ILogger<T>` should not be injected in `MyClass`.

Answer (score 0):

If your class needs to create instances of other classes (I mean here classes that require injection of dependencies, not DTO) you have few possibilities and it really depends on your use case.

If you need to inject specific class, than DI container will handle it for you. Generally DI containers I used usually want all the injected types to be registered so in your case it could look like this:

First you register the `MyNestedClass`

```
services.AddTransient<MyNestedClass, MyNestedClass>();
```

It looks wierd, cause you don't have interface, but it'll work. Not sure, if there's an override, that allows

```
services.AddTransient<MyNestedClass>();
```

but you can try it, maybe there's.
Than in `MyClass` add property for storing `MyNestedClass`:

```
private readonly MyNestedClass nested;

public MyClass(ILogger logger, MyNestedClass nested)
{
    ...
    this.nested = nested;
}
```

And in `Run()` you can go with:

```
public void Run()
{
    this.nested.Run();
}
```

Not sure, why you use `ActivatorUtilities`, I'd just use serviceProvider directly:

```
var myClass = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyClass>();
```

And comment in your code "Surely this isn't right" is right. Generally if you're using `new` on something that isn't DTO it's a red flag. It's not always wrong, but usually it's a code smell at least.

Answer (score 0):

> How do you propagate dependencies through a large codebase using Dependency Injection

You do this by solely applying the [Constructor Injection](https://freecontent.manning.com/understanding-constructor-injection/) pattern, which means you pass in ([volatile](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-1/220)) dependencies of a consuming class as constructor arguments of that consuming class. This allows you to build large and complex object graphs in large code bases with ease.

The following is a fully-functioning refactoring of your code, which adheres to DI principles:

```cs
interface IWorker
{
    void DoSomeWork();
}

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddSeriLog());
        services.AddTransient<MyClass>();
        services.AddTransient<IWorker, MyNestedClass>();
        IServiceProvider container = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        var myClass = container.GetRequiredService<MyClass>();
        myClass.Run();
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    private readonly MyNestedClass _worker;
    public MyClass(IWorker worker) { _worker = worker; }
    public void Run() => _worker.DoSomeWork();
}

class MyNestedClass : IWorker
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyNestedClass> _logger;
    public MyNestedClass(ILogger<MyNestedClass> logger) { _logger = logger; }
    public void DoSomeWork() { }
}
```

What this refactoring does is the following:

- It changes all classes to only depend on what they need directly, which in this case means that `MyClass` is injected with a `MyNestedClass` as constructor argument, instead of letting `MyClass` created a `MyNestedClass` internally. This prevents you from having to provide all dependencies that `MyNestedClass` needs to `MyClass` and prevents `MyClass` from changing in case `MyNestedClass` (or on of its dependencies) changes. It makes your code more resilient to change.
- It registers all components (i.e. `MyClass` and `MyNestedClass`) that are created by the container up front in the `Program` class. When a DI Container needs to create a type, it typically needs to be told about its existence. This might seem inefficient, but once you get more types to register, you might want to make use of Auto-Registration as way to minimize the amount of code you need to write inside the startup path of the application, a.k.a. the [Composition Root.](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/)
- One you have an object structure, you want to, ideally, let the DI Container create that whole graph at once. In this example, the DI Container creates the graph containing `MyClass`, `MyNestedClass`, and `Logger<MyNestedClass>` automatically in one call to `GetRequiredService<MyClass>`.
- The example does not use `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<T>` as this a method that should only be used in rare exceptions.
- The relationship between `MyClass` and `MyNestedClass` is made loosely coupled by the introduction of the `IWorker` abstraction. This simplifies testing of `MyClass`, makes it easier to swap implementations, and simpler to add cross-cutting concerns. This is effectively the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).